# Can't encode multiple characters into unary, only single ones

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to encode a string into unary but for some reason it only works for single letters.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import math

message = input()

def getNumberFromString(string):
    got = ""
    for item in bytes(string, "ascii"):
        got += str(item)
    return int(got)

def getBinaryFromNumber(number):
    return int("{0:b}".format(number))

def encode(number):
    current = None
    number = str(number)
    got = ""

    for letter in number:
        if letter == "0":
            if current != "0":
                current = "0"
                got += " 00 "
            got += "0"
        else:
            if current != "1":
                current = "1"
                got += " 0 "
            got += "0"

    return got[1:]

gotNumber = getNumberFromString(message)
gotBinary = getBinaryFromNumber(gotNumber)
print(encode(gotBinary))
```

It's a challenge on codingame.com, https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/chuck-norris

For single letter strings it works fine, such as C.
But for CC for example, it returning a wrong unary:

Message CC:

**Failure**

**Found: 0 00 00 0 0 0 00 00 0 00 00 0 0 0000**

**Expected: 0 0 00 0000 0 000 00 0000 0 00**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the bits of every character into a single string of bits before processing the sequences of 1's and 0s

For example:

```
def unarize(S):
    bits  = "".join(f"{ord(c):07b}" for c in S)
    bits  = bits.replace("01","0 0 1").replace("10","1 00 0")
    return "00 "[bits>"1":] + bits.replace("1","0")


print(unarize("CC"))
        
# 0 0 00 0000 0 000 00 0000 0 00

print(unarize("LOL"))

# 0 0 00 00 0 00 00 00 0 0 00 00 0 00000 00 00 0 00 00 00
```

*BTW, The real Chuck Norris would likely be more efficient and only require the 0/00 indicator once at the beginning of the result since afterward the sequences of zeros alternate between representing 1s and 0s. The 0/00 in front of every subsequent block is redundant and Chuck Norris does not make redundant moves.*